# Defining classes of quoted triples in RDF-star/RDF 1.2

Tags: rdf, owl, turtle-rdf, rdf-star

RDF-star (soon to be RDF 1.2) introduces a new term, quoted triples, that can be the subject or object of a triple. In the Turtle 1.2 syntax, an example of a basic quoted triple would be written:

```
<<  <IRI1>  <IRI2>  <IRI3>  >>
```

Now suppose that I want to have the range of a property include not just a specific quoted triple but a class containing certain kinds of quoted triples. In particular, the quoted triples I want to allow in the range of the property are of the form:

```
<<  (instance of class C)  (predicate P)  (instance of class C)  >>
```

How does one define the class of quoted triples of this form in RDF 1.2/RDF-star, so that one can say that the range of a property includes instances of that class?

I tried using something like the following:

```
<predicate1>
  rdf:type  owl:ObjectProperty;
  rdfs:range  [ 
                rdf:type  owl:Class;
                [
                 << [rdf:type <classC>] <predicateP> [rdf:type <classC>] >>
                ]
              ].
```

However, I don't think that what follows `owl:class` is even valid Turtle 1.2, much less that it is semantically correct. (I am also not sure if there are reliable Turtle 1.2/Turtle-star validators, so recommendations there are also appreciated.)

Comment: I would say your effort is premature. RDF 1.2 has not yet been published as a Candidate Recommendation (CR), never mind a Technical Recommendation (TR). Any "Turtle 1.2/Turtle-star validators" you might try today would be equally premature. You *might* raise your question to the [W3C RDF-star WG](https://www.w3.org/groups/wg/rdf-star/tools/), via mailing list or GitHub repository, as it might impact our ongoing work.

Comment: @TallTed Thanks for this. My understanding (as a non-expert) is that RDF-star, though not yet an official W3C standard, is used in several RDF-based applications (e.g. Apache Jena and GraphDB). I would think that there probably is some standard way of defining classes of quoted triples for these apps, only because its a fairly obvious use of quoted triples. Are you aware of any resources on this?

Also, are there any free/open-source ontology editors that support quoted triples? I've been using Protege but there is no such support (TopQuadrant advertises support but it's enterprise only).

Comment: All implementations to date are based on draft versions of `RDF-star` (previously known as `RDF*`), which is expected to be known as `RDF 1.2`, when complete. There is no guarantee that any two implementations of those drafts are compatible with each other today, nor that they will be compatible with implementations of the final `RDF 1.2`.